# Why do we have the word "passageway"?

Tags: word-choice

Wouldn't the word "passage" suffice?  (That isn't enough of a reason for "passageway" not to exist, though.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From logic and memory I'll suppose that **passage** stems from the same root as, for example the English verb **to pass**, and French **passer**.

Which almost certainly implies that **passage** originally would have simply meant physical movement. The passage of time, a passage in a book, etc., would just be later extensions to meaning, based on metaphorical usage.

Thus **passageway** (doubtless originally two words) would have been coined to mean the actual path, corridor, or whatever through which passage took place. In practice, people often don't bother making a distinction between the movement itself and the route thereof, so **passage** often gets used for both / either.

Unlike EL&U, which formally tries to identify and weed out duplicate questions, the English language itself doesn't have a design committee to weed out words we could survive without. Anyway, I *like* having the choice of which to use.

Answer (score 5):

It is a less ambiguous than passage which can be, for example, the 'passage of time' or a passage in a book. A passageway always means a physical space. If the context is ambiguous then 'passageway' may clarify it.

Comment: The passage of a train is the train going by; the passageway is the hall.

Answer (score 3):

Obviously, synonyms will exist and two being similar to each other isn't really too surprising. "Way" seems to take it to an extreme, however:

- wayside / side
- alleyway / alley
- driveway / drive
- hallway / hall
- hatchway / hatch

The practice of using *-way* to more directly imply a path or location of travel is ridiculously common:

- archway
- doorway
- fairway
- expressway
- flyway
- gangway

And the list goes on. Etymonline has [some good comments](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=way&searchmode=none) on them. Many of the group are flagged as American English but the dates extend past the birth of the colonies.

Comment: I think *-way* more than *implies* a path - in context, it's an exact synonym. Which makes me suddenly aware of the 'tautology' of *pathway*. Torpenhow Hill is worse, I guess, but I only know of that because of the quadruple tautology. I never noticed *pathway* before.

Comment: @Fumble: The distinction is that _alley_, _drive_, _hall_ etc. can also imply a path. The key is that -way _more directly_ implies a path.

Comment: I don't really understand. Yes, the others all imply a *path*. They all imply a *way* too, simply because in this context *way* and *path* are equivalent. The word *pathway* is tautological, by any logic I can follow.